# Pythagorean triples where the sum of the two cubes is also a square

Tags: number-theory

Are there any Primitive Pythagorean triple solutions $(a,b,c)$ where the sum of the two cubes is also a square? In other words are there coprime $a,b>0 \in \mathbb{N} \;, (a,b)=1$  where $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and $a^3+b^3=d^2$ for some $c,d \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're requiring primitivity? The answer might well be different without it, since your last equation is no longer homogeneous.

Comment: You can just multiply $a$, $b$ and $c$ by any $n^2$ and $d$ by $n^3$ (for any $n\in\mathbb N$) to form a new solution if you have one, so it makes some kind of sense to rule that out, but that's not the same as requiring primitivity, which I also don't see a reason for.

Comment: Because we can always find a trivial solution i.e. $3^3+4^3=91$, if use that as a common factor $a=3.91, b=4.91$ then $a^3+b^3 = 91^3(3^3+4^3)=91^4$ which is square

Comment: But doesn't that just mean that we can find solutions where the triple isn't primitive, not that all solutions where the triple isn't primitive is trivial (in that sense)? I.e. might solutions where the triple isn't primitive not still be interesting?

Comment: Yes, they might, I guess "Interest" is subjective. My interest is the existence of a coprime solution

Comment: I checked the pairs $(u/v)$ with $1\le u,v\le 10^5$ and $\gcd(u,v)=1$ and created the triples $a=u^2-v^2$ , $b=2uv$ , $c=u^2+v^2$. No solution was found in this range.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** These are some unfinished thoughts I will leave here to work on later, or for others to continue.

---

Given that $a$ and $b$ are coprime, it follows that $\gcd(a+b,a^2-ab+b^2)$ divides $3$ because
$$\gcd(a+b,a^2-ab+b^2)=\gcd(a+b,3b^2)=\gcd(a+b,3).$$
Suppose towards a contradiction that the gcd equals $3$: Then the factorization
$$d^2=a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2),$$
shows that there exist $e,f\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that
$$a+b=3e^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad a^2-ab+b^2=3f^2,$$
from which it quickly follows that
$$9e^4=(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=3c^2-6f^2,$$
and reducing mod $8$ yields a contradiction, so the gcd is $1$. Hence there exist $e,f\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that
$$a+b=e^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad a^2-ab+b^2=f^2,$$
and in the same way as before we find that
$$e^4=(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=3c^2-2f^2.$$
Luckily $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$ is a UFD, and we have
$$N((3c-2f)+(c-f)\sqrt{6}):=
\left((3c-2f)+(c-f)\sqrt{6}\right)\left((3c-2f)-(c-f)\sqrt{6}\right)
=3c^2-2f^2=e^4.$$
The gcd of two conjugate factors divides $2(3c-2f)$ and $2(c-f)$, and because $c$ and $f$ are coprime it follows that the gcd divides $2$. Because their product $e^4=(a+b)^2$ is odd, the two conjugate factors are in fact coprime. This means there exists some $x+y\sqrt{6}\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$ such that
$$(3c-2f)+(c-f)\sqrt{6}=(x+y\sqrt{6})^4.\tag{1}$$
This immediately tells us that
$$a+b=e^2=\sqrt{N((3c-2f)+(c-f)\sqrt{6})}=(x+y\sqrt{6})^2(x-y\sqrt{6})^2=(x^2-6y^2)^2.\tag{2}$$
Furthermore, expanding equation $(1)$ yields the two equations
$$3c-2f=x^4+36x^2y^2+36y^4\qquad\text{ and }\qquad c-f=4x^3y+24xy^3.$$
Because $c-f>0$, without loss of generality $x,y>0$. The above tells us that
\begin{eqnarray*}
c&=&x^4-\ 8x^3y+36x^2y^2-48xy^3+36y^4,\\
f&=&x^4- 12x^3y+36x^2y^2-72xy^3+36y^4,
\end{eqnarray*}
and hence that
$$ab=c^2-f^2=(c-f)(c+f)=8xy(x^2+6y^2)(x^4-10x^3y+36x^2y^2-60xy^3+36y^4).\tag{3}$$
This means $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the quadratic polynomial
$$Z^2-(x^2-6y^2)^2Z+8xy(x^2+6y^2)(x^4-10x^3y+36x^2y^2-60xy^3+36y^4).$$
This polynomial has integer roots if and only if its discriminant $\Delta$ is a square, where
$$\Delta=(x^2-6y^2)^4-32xy(x^2+6y^2)(x^4-10x^3y+36x^2y^2-60xy^3+36y^4),$$
which leaves me with the question of when this homogeneous octic polynomial takes on square values.

Answer (score 1):

A partial, in progress answer: $a,b$ satisfies
$$
a=m^2-n^2=rs,\quad b = 2mn=\frac{(3r+s)(s-r)}{4}
$$
for integers $m,n,r,s$ such that
$$
\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(r,s)=1
$$
and $r,s$ are odd, $s\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$ and exactly one of $m,n$ is odd. It can be shown that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ using either $m,n$ or $r,s$. Perhaps this system is already not solvable.

The only other restriction remaining is
$$
a+b=u^2
$$
for some integer $u$.

A sanity check:
$$
a^2+b^2 = (m^2+n^2)^2
$$
and
$$
a^2-ab+b^2 = \left(\frac{3r^2+s^2}{4}\right)^2 = v^2 \in \mathbb Z
$$
Hence if $a+b=u^2$ then
$$
a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2) = (uv)^2
$$

---

Let $a,b,c$ be a primitive Pythagorean triplet. Then we know that for some integers $m>n$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$,
$$
a=m^2-n^2,\quad b=2mn,\quad c = m^2+n^2
$$
In particular, $m,n$ also have different parity.

> **Proposition 1.** Let $a,b,c$ be a primitive Pythagorean triplet such that
>   $$
> a=m^2-n^2,\quad b=2mn,\quad c = m^2+n^2
> $$
>   and $m>n,\;\;\gcd(m,n)=1$. If
>   $$
> a^3+b^3=d^2,
> $$
>   for some integer $d$ then
>   \begin{align}
> a+b &= u^2\\
> a^2-ab+b^2 &= v^2
> \end{align}
>   for some integers $u,v$.

**Proof.** We start with
$$
(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2) = a^3+b^3 = d^2
$$
Since
$$
3a^2 = (2a-b)(a+b) + (a^2-ab+b^2)
$$
This shows that
$
\gcd(a+b,a^2-ab+b^2)
$
divides $3a^2$. Checking $\pmod 3$, the equation
$$
a+b = m^2+2mn-n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3
$$
is possible only if $m,n\equiv 0\pmod 3$. This contradicts $\gcd(m,n)=1$, therefore $3\nmid a+b$. Hence $\gcd(a+b,a^2-ab+b^2)$ divides $a^2$. Now if a prime $p$ divides $\gcd(a+b,a^2-ab+b^2)$, then $p$ divides $a^2$ and hence $p\mid a$. But that means $p$ divides $b$, contradicting $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Hence we conclude that
$$
\gcd(a+b,a^2-ab+b^2)=1
$$
As a result, we can write
$$
\begin{align}
a+b &= u^2\\
a^2-ab+b^2 &= v^2
\end{align}
$$
for some integers $u,v$. (It cannot have been $-u^2,-v^2$ instead since $a,b>0$.)
$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

---

For the equation
$$
a^2-ab+b^2=v^2,
$$
since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ we must have $\gcd(a,v)=\gcd(b,v)=1$.

> **Proposition 2.** The primitive integer solutions to
>   $$
> a^2-ab+b^2 = v^2
> $$
>   are
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> a &= rs\\
> b &= \frac{(3r-s)(r+s)}{4}\text{ or }\frac{(3r+s)(s-r)}{4}\\
> v &= \frac{3r^2+s^2}{4}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where $r,s$ are odd integers satisfying $\gcd(r,s)=1$.

**Proof.** We first convert the equation to
$$
a^2-ab+b^2=v^2 \Longleftrightarrow (2b-a)^2 + 3a^2 = (2v)^2
$$

Following [The Solution of the Diophantine Equation$X^2+3Y^2=Z^2$](http://www.m-hikari.com/ija/ija-2014/ija-13-16-2014/abdelalimIJA13-16-2014.pdf),

> **Theorem 2.2** Let $E:x^2+3y^2=z^2$ be the diophantine equation and $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb Z^3$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$, $y$ is odd and $\gcd(xz,3)=1$. Then
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> |x| &= \frac{3r^2-s^2}{2}\\
> |y| &= rs\\
> |z| &= \frac{3r^2+s^2}{2}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   for some odd integers $r,s$ and $\gcd(r,s)=1$. (Not written but implied that $s\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

Since $a$ is already odd, to use this result we need to check that
$$
\gcd(2b-a,a)=1,\quad \gcd((2b-a)(2v),3)=1
$$
The first part is immediate since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a$ is odd. For the second part, if $3\mid v$ or $3\mid 2b-a$ then from
$$
(2b-a)^2+3a^2=v^2
$$
we get $3\mid a$. For both cases $3$ divides $2b-a,a$ so $3$ divides $b$. This contradicts $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Therefore indeed $\gcd((2b-a)(2b),3)=1$, so we obtain the solutions
$$
\begin{align}
|2b-a| &= \frac{3r^2-s^2}{2}\\
|a| &= rs\\
|2v| &= \frac{3r^2+s^2}{2}
\end{align}
$$
for some odd $r,s$ satisfying $\gcd(r,s)=1$. Rearranging:
$$
\begin{align}
a &= rs\\
b &= \frac{(3r-s)(r+s)}{4}\text{ or }\frac{(3r+s)(s-r)}{4}\\
v &= \frac{3r^2+s^2}{4}
\end{align}
$$
which is what we want.
$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

---

This gives us a new restriction:
$$
u^2 = a+b = \frac{3r^2+6rs-s^2}{4} \text{ or } \frac{s^2+6rs-3r^2}{4}
$$
We do a substitution for the odd $r=2f+1,s=2g+1$, giving
$$
u^2 = 2 + 6 f + 3 f^2 + 2 g + 6 f g - g^2
$$
or
$$
u^2 = 1 - 3 f^2 + 4 g + 6 f g + g^2
$$
For the first equation, LHS $\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$ but RHS $\equiv 2,3\pmod 4$, which is impossible. Therefore it must have been
$$
a=m^2-n^2=rs,\quad b = 2mn=\frac{(3r+s)(s-r)}{4}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that such integers exist and write, say, $a=r^2-s^2$ and $b=2rs$ for coprime (positive) integers $r$ and $s$, then
$$
d^2=(r^2+2rs-s^2)(r^4-2r^3s++2r^2s^2+2rs^3+s^4)
$$
and hence a solution would correspond to a (nontrivial) rational point on the (genus $2$) curve
$$
y^2 = x^6 -3x^4+8x^3+3x^2-1.
$$
The Jacobian of this curve has rank $1$ and a Chabauty argument in Magma using the prime $17$ shows that there are no such points. There may be an easier way to see this, but I'm afraid it's not obvious to me.

Comment: What area of maths do I need to investigate in order to understand how you derived the equation in $x,y$ and the subsequent claims.

Comment: Multiply out the first equation (in $r, s$ and $d$) and then divide by $s^6$. The machinery needed to understand Chabauty's method is quite advanced. A book by Cassels and Flynn ("Prolegomena....") is a good place to start, but assumes a solid undergraduate background.

Comment: @user1035795 From $a^2+b^2=c^2$ you get the primitive pythagorean parameterization $a=r^2-s^2,b=2rs$, then a substitution into $d^2=a^3+b^3$ gives you equation 1. Next since $s\neq 0$, let $y=d/s^3$ and $x=r/s$ to get the curve over $\mathbb Q$ as in equation 2.

Comment: Thank you Mike, yes plain as day now you (and Yong Hao Ng) pointed out. I'll check out the Chabauty method, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

equations  $$X^3+Y^3=Z^2$$

Can be expressed by integers  $p,s,a,b,c$ .  where the number of  $c$ characterizes the degree of primitiveness.

$$X=(3a^2+4ab+b^2)(3a^2+b^2)c^2$$

$$Y=2b(a+b)(3a^2+b^2)c^2$$

$$Z=3(a+b)^2(3a^2+b^2)^2c^3$$

And more.

$$X=2b(b-a)(3a^2+b^2)c^2$$

$$Y=2b(b+a)(3a^2+b^2)c^2$$

$$Z=4b^2(3a^2+b^2)^2c^3$$

If we decide to factor $$X^3+Y^3=qZ^2$$

For a compact notation we replace :

$$a=s(2p-s)$$

$$b=p^2-s^2$$

$$t=p^2-ps+s^2$$

then:

$$X=qb(a+b)c^2$$

$$Y=qa(a+b)c^2$$

$$Z=qt(a+b)^2c^3$$

And the most beautiful solution. If we use the solutions of Pell's equation: $p^2-3a^2s^2=1$

by the way $a$ May appear as a factor in the decision and.
Then the solutions are of the form::

$$X=qa(2p-3as)sc^2$$

$$Y=q(p-2as)pc^2$$

$$Z=q(p^2-3aps+3a^2s^2)c^3$$

If we change the sign : $$Y^3-X^3=qZ^2$$

Then the solutions are of the form:

$$X=qa(2p+3as)sc^2$$

$$Y=q(p+2as)pc^2$$

$$Z=q(p^2+3aps+3a^2s^2)c^3$$

Another solution of the equation: $$X^3+Y^3=qZ^2$$

$p,s$ - integers asked us.

To facilitate the calculations we make the change. $a,b,c$

If the ratio is as follows : $q=3t^2+1$

$$b=2q(q+2\mp{6t})p^2+6p(t\mp1)ps+(q-1\mp{3t})s^2$$

$$c=6q(q-2(1\pm{t}))p^2+6q(t\mp1)ps+3(1\mp{t})s^2$$

$$a=12q(1\mp{t})p^2+6(4t\mp{q})ps+3(1\mp{t})s^2$$

If the ratio is as follows: $q=t^2+3$

$$b=3(q-1)(1\pm{t})s^2+2(3\pm{(q-1)t})ps+(1\pm{t})p^2$$

$$c=3(6-(q-1)(q-3\mp{t}))s^2+6(1\pm{t})ps+(q-3\pm{t})p^2$$

$$a=3(6-(q-1)(1\mp{t}))s^2+6(1\pm{t})ps+(1\pm{t})p^2$$

Then the solutions are of the form:

$$X=2c(c-b)$$

$$Y=(c-3b)(c-b)$$

$$Z=3a(c-b)^2$$

Then the solutions are of the form:

$$X=2(c-b)c$$

$$Y=2(c+b)c$$

$$Z=4ac^2$$

If the ratio is as follows : $q=t^2+3$

$$c=6(q-4)(2\pm{t})p^2+4(6\pm{(q-4)t})ps+2(2\pm{t})s^2$$

$$b=3(24-(q-4)(q-3\mp{2t}))p^2+12(2\pm{t})ps+(q-3\pm{2t})s^2$$

$$a=3(24-(q-4)(4\mp{2t}))p^2+12(2\pm{t})ps+2(2\pm{t})s^2$$

If the ratio is as follows   $q=3t^2+4$

$$c=q(-q+7(4\mp{3t}))p^2+6q(t\mp{1})ps+(q-4\mp{3t})s^2$$

$$b=3q(2q-7(1\pm{t}))p^2+6q(t\mp{1})ps+3(1\mp{t})s^2$$

$$a=21q(1\mp{t})p^2+6(7t\mp{q})ps+3(1\mp{t})s^2$$

Then the solutions are of the form :

$$X=2(3c-2b)c$$

$$Y=2(3c+2b)c$$

$$Z=12ac^2$$

Then the solutions are of the form :

$$X=(2b-c)b$$

$$Y=(2b+c)b$$

$$Z=2ab^2$$

Comment: So with all of that can you give an example solution?